# How do I fix the validation error I am getting about my <style> tag

Tags: html, css, validation

So I have this HTML file and it's giving me two validation errors and I have no idea how to fix it, I think it's because the style is out of scope but I have no idea where to place it, been playing around with it for a good hour or so now.
As you can see below I added a picture showing the validation errors using this website https://validator.w3.org/nu/#file

is this a scope issue or what is going on here?

[image]

And if I add it in the  I get this
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <title>ComputerFix</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head> 

    <style>
            main { 
                display:flex;    width: 100%;
                align-items:center;
                justify-content:center;
            }

            label {
                display:block;
            }
        </style>


    <body class="StandardBackground"> 
        <div id="navbar"> 
            <ul> 
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li> 
                <li><a href="information.html">Information</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="download.html">Download</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </div> 


        <main>
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Kontakta oss</legend>
                    <div>
                        <label for='name'>Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name='name'>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for='email'>Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" name='email'>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for='phone'>Telefonnummer:</label>
                        <input type="text" name='phone'>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for='meddelande'>Meddelande:</label>
                        <textarea name='meddelande'></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type='submit'>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

            </form>
        </main>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, have you tried placing it inside `<head>`?

Comment: I did try that, and it threw alot of other errors.

Comment: What kind of errors?

Comment: I just updated the question feel free to give it a quick peek

Comment: Argh. **Quote** error messages. Don't show screenshots of them. It makes them really hard to read, and even harder to copy/paste from!

Comment: The 2nd set of errors is not from the `<style>`, so you can already assume that the `<style>` is now okay

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Placement of `<style>` should be in the `<head>` and the form inputs should be using ids, not names in order to validate.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>ComputerFix</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
      main {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      label {
        display: block;
      }

    </style>
  </head>




  <body class="StandardBackground">
    <div id="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="information.html">Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="download.html">Download</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>


    <main>
      <form>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Kontakta oss</legend>
          <div>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="phone">Telefonnummer:</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="meddelande">Meddelande:</label>
            <textarea name="meddelande" id="meddelande"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="submit">
          </div>
        </fieldset>

      </form>
    </main>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Form controls need names! They need an id **as well** for the label element to reference them in the for attribute, but the `name` is essential for  them to be successful controls which appear in submitted form data.

Comment: I never said it wasn't valid. I just said the form wouldn't submit any data without them. Validity is not the beginning and end of QA.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. OP is lucky.

Answer (score 2):

A `<style>` element must appear inside the `<head>` element. You have put it between the `<head>` and `<body>` elements where nothing is allowed.

---

The `for` attribute of a `<label>` needs to reference the `id` of the associated form control, not the `name`. (Multiple elements can share a name, which makes it unsuitable for associating anything with a particular element).

Answer (score -1):

The `for` in your label refers to the `id` of the desired element:

```
   <div>
        <label for='name'>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name='name' id='name'>
    </div>
```

Check it out here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Answer (score -4):

As already pointed out, make 2 corrections to your code :

1.) Put the Style tags  between the head opening and closing tags. This is a strict criteria for internal CSS.

2.) The **for** attribute used by you in the form uses the value of "**id**" and not "**name**". So put another attribute in the input tag id="name"  OR id="email" or whatever.